# Facebook page long term access token

Tags: facebook, token

While the Facebook document seems complete about depreciating the offline access token, I appear to be stumped in my own case. My access tokens have decreased to a lifetime of about two hours which, running my pages from a CRON job, is causing chaos. It worked fine for about four months until last week.

Here is my code. Any ideas what to add here? I have the manage_pages permission and, as I say, it used to work fine.

```
try {
$page_info = $facebook->api("/$news_page?fields=access_token");
if ( !empty($page_info['access_token']) )   {
    $tkk = $page_info['access_token'];
    $r = mysql('database', "update facebook set access_token = '$tkk' where email='$news_email'");

    $args = array(
        'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
        'message'       => $u,
        'link'          => $news_url,
        'description'   => $news_text,
        'name'          => $news_title,
        'picture'       => $image
    );

    $post_id = $facebook->api("/$news_page/feed","post",$args);
}
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
error_log($e);
$user = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been [flagged as a known bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/341793929223330) by Facebook. Just have to sit back and wait :(